# Perl script to convert logged datetimes to UNIX epoch timestamps

Tags: perl, grep, timestamp, epoch

I have a log file (`datetimes.log`) consisting of hundreds of thousands of timestamps of the form:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
```

For example:

```
2013-03-28 06:43:51
2013-03-28 06:43:55
2013-03-28 06:44:03
...etc.
```

I'd like to write a simple Perl script to output a new `unix_timestamps.log` file that contains the same entries, but instead of the datetime, to have the corresponding UNIX epoch timestamp. For the example above, the `unix_timestamps.log` file would have the following info in it:

```
1364453031
1364453035
1364453043
...etc.
```

The only thing I can think of is `perl convert_2_timestamps.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

grep m/_(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/ | POSIX::mktime(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) > unix_timestamps.log
```

But not sure how to transfer the parameters into `mktime`, and not sure if this is even the right approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually want this to be combined with your previous question? Since you don't really know what your doing, maybe you should just tell us what it is you want to achieve in the end. That makes things a lot easier. ;-)

Comment: What time zone is used? local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;


my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
  on_error => 'croak',
);

while( <DATA> ) {
   my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime($_);
   print $dt->epoch, "\n";
}

__DATA__
2013-03-28 06:43:51
2013-03-28 06:43:55
2013-03-28 06:44:03
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: I've switched to using Time::Piece for simple parsing tasks like this. You're far less likely to get people complaining that they can't install modules from CPAN :-)

Comment: @Dave that was my way, you know, TIMTOWTDI. But there are chances to install CPAN modules in different scenarios.

Comment: Oh, of course there are! But I've found that by using core modules, where available, you can concentrate on solving the problem rather going off on a whole side discussion about how non-admins can install CPAN modules. It's just pragmatism on my part :-)

Comment: I agree, it's clever avoid potential problems

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use for the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module which has been a standard part of the Perl distribution for over five years.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

# Read the data a record at a time. Data ends up in $_.
# N.B. Using built-in DATA filehandle for this demo.
#      In the real world you'd open a separate filehandle.
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  # Create a Time::Piece object using strptime (that's "string
  # parse time") and immediately call the epoch method on the
  # new object to get the value you want.
  say Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')->epoch;
}

__DATA__
2013-03-28 06:43:51
2013-03-28 06:43:55
2013-03-28 06:44:03
```

Answer (score 1):

You could break up the YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format like so:

```
my ( $y, $m, @t ) = split /[-: ]+/, $time_str;
my $time = mktime( reverse @t, $m - 1, $y - 1900 );
```

But you could also put it in a replace like so:

```
s{(\d{4})-(0?[1-9]\d?)-(0?[1-9]\d?) (0?\d{1,2}):(0?\d{1,2}):(0?\d{1,2})}{
    mktime( $6, $5, $4, $3, $2 - 1, $1 - 1900 )
 }e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Date::Parse` CPAN module. ([http://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse](http://metacpan.org/pod/Date%3a%3aParse))

With it, your `convert_2_timestamps.pl` can be just:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Parse;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  printf("%s\n", str2time("$_ GMT"));
}
```

Note that I had to append GMT to your example input to get your expected output.

Run as:

```
perl convert_2_timestamps.pl < datetimes.log > unix_timestamps.log
```